# which approach: native app or HTML5 for my radio website?

Tags: android, ios, html, cordova

I have created an HTML5 site for streaming music from radio stations.
now I decided to have it on android and ios devices. I also created mobile version of site.

```
m.youcontroltheradio.com
```

now I stuck in which decision is better: should I use phoneGap (HTML5 wrapper) or develop native app for both devices? (this app plays music, need to record sound, need to save its state after force closing it)
I think this app one day should support million of users.

thanks in advance

Comment: native - for best performance

Answer (score 1):

if you have already developed the application in Html , i think you should opt for packaging it through phonegap ( after all thats what the motive is .. write once run everywhere ) ! And Packaging through phonegap using cordova for an already developed app is not that tedious. Also , if it works well you can go packaging with ios as Well !
Hope it helps.